# Changing Flash setting of Android Camera 2 at runtime

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-camera2

Basically, what I am trying to do is change the CONTROL_AE_MODE by button click in the app. The user can use AUTO flash(ON_AUTO_FLASH), turn if ON(ON_ALWAYS_FLASH), or OFF(CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF).

In this example: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java

Line 818, they set the flash once:

```
// Use the same AE and AF modes as the preview.
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
            setAutoFlash(captureBuilder);

            // Orientation
            int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));

            CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback CaptureCallback
                    = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session,
                                               @NonNull CaptureRequest request,
                                               @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                    showToast("Saved: " + mFile);
                    Log.d(TAG, mFile.toString());
                    unlockFocus();
                }
            };

            mCaptureSession.stopRepeating();
            mCaptureSession.capture(captureBuilder.build(), CaptureCallback, null);
```

And then builds the CaptureSession at line 840.

Is there a way to change the CONTROL_AE_MODE after the preview is made?

I have tried remaking the session, which kinda worked:

```
if(flashMode == CameraView.CAMERA_FLASH_ON){
            Log.e("CAMERA 2", "FLASH ON");
            mPreviewCaptureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_ALWAYS_FLASH);
        }else if(flashMode == CameraView.CAMERA_FLASH_OFF){
            Log.e("CAMERA 2", "FLASH OFF");
            mPreviewCaptureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF);
        }else if(flashMode == CameraView.CAMERA_FLASH_AUTO){
            Log.e("CAMERA 2", "FLASH AUTO");
            mPreviewCaptureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH);
        }
        mFlashMode = flashMode;
        if (mCameraCaptureSession != null) {
            mCameraCaptureSession.close();
            mCameraCaptureSession = null;
       }
  createCameraPreviewSession();
```

For some reason, CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF would turn the whole preview black.
I tried looking in the docs for methods to update but haven't found anything.

Any tutorials or docs is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you fixed this issue? CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF gets black for me too.

Comment: maybe you have piece of example? or just tell me where exactlly i should to incdlude this lines of code? on `stillCapture()` or `onConfigurate()` or `unlockFocus()` medhod? because i can't find anythink that can make my code worked...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why your preview turn black, but you don't need to close capture session manually. From `.close()` method's docs:

> Using `createCaptureSession(List , CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback,
>   Handler)` directly without closing is the recommended approach for
>   quickly switching to a new session, since unchanged target outputs can
>   be reused more efficiently.

So you can reuse existing CaptureRequest.Builder, set your changed value, build new PreviewRequest and just start new session with this new request, like this:

```
try {
    // Change some capture settings
    mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON);
    // Build new request (we can't just edit existing one, as it is immutable)
    mPreviewRequest = mPreviewRequestBuilder.build();
    // Set new repeating request with our changed one
    mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequest, mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
} catch (CameraAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It will be much faster (almost without any visible freeze of preview).

Comment: maybe you have piece of example? or just tell me where exactlly i should to incdlude this lines of code? on `stillCapture()` or `onConfigurate()` or `unlockFocus()` medhod? because i can't find anythink that can make my code worked...

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned by @cyborg86pl when switching flash modes you should not switch `CONTROL_AE_MODE` . Instead you can switch between `FLASH_MODE`´s. Here is a working example for my case:

```
  when (currentFlashState) {
        FlashState.AUTO -> {
          previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH)
        }
        FlashState.ON -> {
          previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON)
          previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CameraMetadata.FLASH_MODE_TORCH)
        }
        FlashState.OFF -> {
          previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON)
          previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_OFF)
        }
      }
 previewRequest = previewRequestBuilder.build()
 captureSession.setRepeatingRequest(previewRequest, captureCallback, backgroundHandler)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is disabling flash, not auto-exposure (AE), thus you want to use `CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON` rather than `CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF`.

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata.html#CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON):

> CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON
>
> The camera device's autoexposure routine is active, with no flash control.