# How to Disable All Automatics in Android Camera2 API

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I'm trying to disable auto-exposure, auto-focus, and auto-white-balance in Google's [Camera2Basic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) sample. Here's my code:

```
private void disableAutomatics() {
    try {
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE_OFF);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_VIDEO_STABILIZATION_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_VIDEO_STABILIZATION_MODE_OFF);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.LENS_OPTICAL_STABILIZATION_MODE, CaptureRequest.LENS_OPTICAL_STABILIZATION_MODE_OFF);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE, .2f);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME, 1000000L);

        mPreviewRequest = mPreviewRequestBuilder.build();
        // Set new repeating request with our changed one
        mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequest, mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem is I don't know where to place the method in Camera2BasicFragment.java.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

There are two places where you may want to do those settings:

- If you want to do it before the preview starts, the better place would be inside of the overridden method `onConfigured` within the `createCameraPreviewSession()` void (line 696 in the [Camera2BasicFragment](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java) file provided in the Google's [Camera2Basic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) sample:

  ```
  private void createCameraPreviewSession() {
      try {
          SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
          assert texture != null;

          // We configure the size of default buffer to be the size of camera preview we want.
          texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());

          // This is the output Surface we need to start preview.
          Surface surface = new Surface(texture);

          // We set up a CaptureRequest.Builder with the output Surface.
          mPreviewRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
          mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);

          // Here, we create a CameraCaptureSession for camera preview.
          mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface, mImageReader.getSurface()),
              new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

                  @Override
                  public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                      // The camera is already closed
                      if (null == mCameraDevice) {
                          return;
                      }

                      // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
                      mCaptureSession = cameraCaptureSession;
                      try {


                          //Place here your custom camera settings


                          // Start displaying the camera preview.
                          mPreviewRequest = mPreviewRequestBuilder.build();
                          mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequest,
                                  mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
                      } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                      }
                  }

                  @Override
                  public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                      showToast("Failed");
                  }
              }, null
          );
      } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
  ```
- If you want to do the settings after the preview has started and in runtime just call your `disableAutomatics()` from the UI or anywhere else and it should work fine.

Note that you don't have to close the older `CaptureSession` by calling its `CaptureSession.close()` method as explained in an answer to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35620400/changing-flash-setting-of-android-camera-2-at-runtime) because the new replaces the older one.

---

On another hand, I am not sure about setting the exposure time value manually as you did in your question:

> mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME, 1000000L);

because you may get unexpected results varying on different devices. What I know is that doing so is usually discouraged and it's preferred instead to let the camera adjust by its own and then call AE (auto-exposure) lock:

```
mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_LOCK, true);
```

You can check the `CONTROL_AE_LOCK` reference [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.html#CONTROL_AE_MODE).

But if your code needs a fixed exposure time then it should work.