# how do i turn on set the camera flashlight in automode programatically

Tags: android

i have been developing a camera app in which i want to set the camera in auto mode,i tried the following

```
private void getCamera() {{
            try {
                camera = Camera.open();
                params = camera.getParameters();
                params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
                camera.setParameters(params);
                camera.startPreview();
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        }
```

since the camera class is deprecated this won't work.i couldn't find any alternative for this

Comment: hope this link might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37144657/switch-flash-in-camera2-api

Comment: camera is deprecated , try to use camera2

Comment: you can try that http://stackoverflow.com/q/35620400/1638739